# Getting error in my android programming code java.lang

Tags: java, android, android-activity

this is my java file UserAreaActivity file. check this code and give ans in code format. m using latest version of android studio.

```
package com.symplycode.newloginregister;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        final EditText etUsername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etAge=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final TextView welcomeMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomeMsg);


        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String name= extras.getString("name");
        String username= extras.getString("username");
        String age= extras.getString("age");

        String message = name + "welcome to your user area";
        welcomeMessage.setText(message);
        etUsername.setText(username);
        etAge.setText(age);
    }
}
```

this is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="com.symplycode.newloginregister.UserAreaActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:text="Age" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

getting error in this.. how can i solve this please tell me

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.symplycode.newloginregister/com.symplycode.newloginregister.UserAreaActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final EditText etUsername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etAge=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
```

must be

```
 final TextView etUsername=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final TextView etAge=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
```

You are trying to cast an `TextView` widget to a `EditText` widget. Either change it like my example or change the `TextView` inside your xml layout to `EditText`

By the way, there is no view with the id `etUsername`inside your layout, maybe it´s a typo and you mean `etName` ? Be sure you are using the correct layout xml...

The layout that you set with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);` must be the layout where both views are inside...

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.symplycode.newloginregister/com.symplycode.newloginregister.UserAreaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: ohhhh thanks so much  you are right i corrected my text view id from etusername to etname :)